# WPF virtualization + paging

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, wpfdatagrid

I have to display records from a database. .Net WCF + EF + AutoMapper backend. .Net WPF MVVM-base frontend.

I lazy-load the entire object graph and pass it through a layer of mapping. So to retreive 8000 records/entire graph it takes about 15 seconds.

That's a totally unacceptable loading time.

So I implemented a took method on the service side with following signature:

```
IList<Client> Take(int startIndex, int count)
```

Now I want to use that in my datagrid. I want to first load all the id's of the records (and only them) or the record count, then load the 100 first and finally load the others once the user scroll.

I've looked on bing after informations about how to do that but nothing conclusive.

Do you have any example, articles, sources, that would help me to implement that the right way in an MVVM-base client ?

Also, is my approach right or should I retreive only the root of the object graph and then query the rest of the graph once the user for instance select a particular row ?